# A file instance needs to be constructed inside a lambda expression for FileNameFilter interface

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

Suppose that I have the following directory structure for my test.

```
test
|
|
---test1
|
|
---test2
|
|
---random.txt
```

In this structure, test1 and test2 are directories while random.txt is a regular file.

I want to write a function that will give me a list of all subdirectories given a file path.

Attempt 1, works (no lambda expression)

```
private static ArrayList<String> subDirectories(File pathname) {
    ArrayList<String> subdirectories = new ArrayList<>();

    for(File file : pathname.listFiles()) {
        if(file.isDirectory())
            subdirectories.add(file.getName());
    }

    return subdirectories;
}
```

This correctly returns test1 and test2 as subdirectories.

Attempt 2: using lambda expression

```
private static String[] subDirectories(File pathname) {
    return pathname.list((dir, name) -> dir.isDirectory());
}
```

This result now includes random.txt as a directory, which it is clearly not. Why is the function with lambda giving a different result?

EDIT:

Works only when creating a file instance in the lambda expression:

```
return pathname.list((dir, name) -> new File(dir, name).isDirectory());
```

dir is already a File object however, why are we creating a File instance from an existing File instance?

EDIT 2:

After looking at the documentation, the `dir` parameter always refers to the directory in which the file was found. This is why `random.txt` is returned as the name of a directory. But I still don't know why creating a new File instance is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your existing attempt:

```
private static List<String> subDirectories(File pathname) {
    return Arrays.stream(pathname.listFiles())
                   .filter(File::isDirectory)
                   .map(File::getName)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

The reason why the lambda solution lists `random.txt` is the use of [`FilenameFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) which uses parameters as:

```
/**
 * Tests if a specified file should be included in a file list.
 *
 * @param   dir    the directory in which the file was found.
 * @param   name   the name of the file.
 * @return  true if and only if the name should be
 *          included in the file list; false otherwise.
 */
boolean accept(File dir, String name);
```

as you can relate *`test` is a directory* and that's why *`random.txt` is filtered to output*.

---

**Edit**: Using

```
return pathname.list((dir, name) -> new File(dir, name).isDirectory());
```

works since, you've created a file and not a directory with the name `random.txt`. The reason its not a directory is stated in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,java.lang.String))

> If parent is the *empty* abstract pathname then the new File instance is
>   created by converting child into an abstract pathname and resolving
>   the result against a system-dependent default directory.

which in your case doesn't hold true, since the parent directory exists.

Comment: Oh, this is a nice solution. I have not learned about streams yet but I'll keep this in mind for future reference.

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm Updated with corresponding edits in the question. Try not modifying the question too much though in general.

Answer (score 1):

In your function,

```
private static String[] subDirectories(File pathname) {
    return pathname.list((dir, name) -> dir.isDirectory());
}
```

the first parameter `dir` is the base directory, and `name` is the actual file element which must be tested for being a directory. You could use

```
private static List<String> subDirectories(File pathname) {
    return Arrays.stream(pathname.listFiles())
                   .filter(File::isDirectory)
                   .map(File::getName)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

> Please note that `pathname.listFiles()` will return `null`, when there
>   are no Files, and `Arrays.stream(pathname.listFiles())` will throw a
>   NPE in that case.